# how to make android app containing huge text content

Tags: android, text

I want to make an android app that have a huge text content. imagine that i want to make a dictionary app. so what should i do. what method should i choose. should i make lots of textviews and activities or there is a solution?

I'm newbie in android programming...please help me! I tried by making a lot of textviews and activity manually but it's time-consuming...

Comment: Please clarify your question, show us the things you've tried, and have in mind that you need to consume some time to understand or at very least search for examples...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html you can import words for example from a databases and put them into the listview then dynamically create activities.

Answer (score 0):

If you want TextViews you can always make them by code.

You declare a xml with a scrollView on top and inside a linearlayout.

On the class you do (or something close to that):

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);

for(String text: textList){
    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    valueTV.setText(text);
    valueTV.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    ((LinearLayout) layout).addView(valueTV);
}
```

Hope it helps